# How to repeat text from one page to another to reduce time in updating every month

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, string

I've been looking everywhere and I can't seem to find exactly what I'm looking for, I'm starting to think I should be looking at some kind of Javascript?

Basically, I have an amount £1,000,000 displayed over an image button and I need this repeated on a different page (The page the button leads to).

As I've never done this before I'm not sure where to look or what I need to be looking at as I'm a novice in this area.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: have you looked at `localstorage` and `sessionstorage` ?

Comment: No? As mentioned i'm new to development/css so i'm not completely sure where I should be looking, so I thought i'd ask the community that knows best.

Answer (score 0):

If the value is static so you can use content css property :

https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/CSS/content

If the amount is dynamic you should pass variable through Url or via form.

Answer (score 0):

As I don't have a clue as to what you're setup is, i'll make some assumptions:

- a static HTML site
- no javascript frameworks (so no jQuery or jqLite etc)

with these assumptions you should start by looking up url attributes as a way to communicate basic information between pages.
As an example, the button href should look something like this:

```
/link-to-page?amount=1000000
```

then you grab the amount on the new page - with javascript - looking in the `window.location` object

[This is a good resource](https://davidwalsh.name/query-string-javascript)

Comment: @DavidW No worries :) let me know how you get on. Upvote and mark this answer as the accepted answer if it's helped you